# Why does the method of undetermined coefficients fails for exponential functions for in homogenous ODEs?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

(By the "by the above method" it means the method of letting $y=ke^{rx}$ where $f(x)=e^{rx}$ in differential equations of the form: [image]

)

Now, I tried to confirm that the method fails when $r$ equals one of the roots but I did not find anything special. Can anyone clarify as to why the method fails for finding particular solutions to differential equations when $r$ equals one of the roots of the auxiliary function? And, following this, clarify why the following bullet points are true since I can't see the difference they make from $(ke^{rx}$?

Comment: Put everything you want in the exponent together in brackets; that should work

Comment: I tried that but I got nothing.

Comment: odd. $it^{should}work$.

Comment: By "brackets" Brent means "braces": to get $e^{rx}$ type "e^{rx}".

Comment: Oh, oops.       I'll change it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity's sake, I'm going to call $L[y]$ your differential equation on the left-hand side.

If $r$ is a single root of the auxiliary equation, then $y=e^{rx}$ is a solution to the homogeneuous equation, as well as any scalar multiple of it; in other words, $L[ke^{rx}]=0$. So if you were to try and plug that in while looking for a particular solution, you'd get $0=e^{rx}$, which is a problem.

Comment: Can you clarify as to why if $r$ is a single ringle root of the auxiliary equation then it is a solution to the homogenous equation. Thanks.

Comment: It's fine, I see it.